# How do I connect my ASP.NET application with Epicor ERP?

Tags: asp.net, epicorerp, epicor10

I have an asp.net application that needs to be connected with EPICOR EAM but don't find an example or sample for that. How do I connect to push and retrieve data using web services?

Answer (score 0):

With the implementation of REST API as a base product offering in version 10.1.500, direct web service connections are no longer the best path forward.  The REST implementation guide is available via your Epicweb customer portal at the following URL: https://epicweb.epicor.com/doc/Docs/Epicor10_RestImplementation_102200.pdf
If this link breaks, the guide is proprietary and can be retrieved from your EpicWeb customer portal.

The standard REST interface comes with a built-in swagger deployment to guide you to all of the service endpoints. A word of caution is that there are a lot of nuances to the business logic in Epicor that often requires specific training to identify. If this Epicor-specific technical expertise does not exist within your organization, it might be the lowest hanging fruit to reach out to Epicor professional services or a partner to find out which sequence of method calls to make.